# Stripe exception - "no such payout" when fetching a payout object

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I just received a payout.paid webhook for one of my Connect accounts. I'd like to retrieve the payout object and expand on the balance_transaction and destination properties.

So in one of my controllers I do this just to test and fetch the payout-

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _config["StripeSettings:SecretKey"];
var service = new PayoutService();
Payout payout = service.Get("po_1Mip8FQfrEXkPBakiZX3dTD8");
```

And I receive the exception saying "no such payout po_1Mip8FQfrEXkPBakiZX3dTD8"

**QUESTION** - Is this how I retrieve a payout on a Connect account or is this only looking at my platform account for this payout id?

If this is only looking at my platform account and not through all my Connected accounts, how would I look at the Connect account payout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the Payout that belongs to a connected account, you should include [`Stripe-Account` header](https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts) as connected account ID when making the request. The request will then look at the Payout ID in the connected account: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

If `Stripe-Account` header is not included, the request will only look at the Payout ID in the platform.